# Magento 2: More Information Tab Attribute order

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-view, additional-information

Is it possible to change the attribute order in More Information Tab.

Please refer the screen shot below:

[image]

I want to rearrange order to USP/Features/Benefits. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the order of attributes in frontend by changing the order that they appear on your attribute set.

[image]